# How do you uninstall an extension using the CodenameOne Settings tool in NetBeans?

Tags: codenameone

I installed the braintree, and other, extension into my project in NetBeans. I no longer want to use the extension. There does not seem to be a way to remove the extension using the Settings tool. Removing the libraries from the project does not seem to remove the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove the files with the name of the extension (cn1lib and the ver file) from the lib directory (you can see it in the files tab)
- Open `Codename One Settings -> Build Hints` and remove the `ios.*` and `android.*` entries you didn't add manually
- Right click project and select `Codename One -> Refresh Client Libs`

Comment: I tried that suggestion, but the braintree extension stays installed.  I tried deleting the references from the build hints manually, but still does not correct the issue.

Comment: Did you remove the cn1lib file?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to successfully resolve the problem using the supplied solution. I was not correctly removing the files from the project library.